# Javascript differences between window properties

Tags: javascript, object, reference, window, screen

Could someone please tell me the difference between these?
window.screenY and window.screenTop 
as well as 
window.screenX and window.screenLeft

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`window.screenY` and `window.screenTop` both return the same result

`window.screenX` and `window.screenLeft` both return the same result

But `IE <= 8` doesnt support `window.screenY` and `window.screenX`.

`Firefox < 64` doesnt support `window.screenTop` and `window.screenLeft`.

Use conditionally for browser compatibility like this

```
var winTop = window.screenTop ? window.screenTop : window.screenY;
var winLeft = window.screenLeft ? window.screenLeft : window.screenX;
```

Comment: Thanks!! very helpful.